# LINQ to Entities does not recognize 'System.DateTime AddMinutes(Double)' method

Tags: c#, linq

Runtime Error that says what the title shows...
My Linq is as follows in my controller:

```
     var TestingLinq = (from a in db.shp_master
                         join b in db.shp_status on a.serialnbr equals b.serialnbr into b_join
                         from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where
                                   a.shipto == "1022a" &&
                                   a.status == "s" &&
                                   b.status == "s" &&
                                   a.shpreq == 0
                         group new {a, b} by new {
                                   a.serialnbr,
                                   a.trailer,
                                   a.shipto
                         } into g
                         orderby
                                   g.Key.serialnbr
                         select new RecieveTruck {
                                   SerialNumber = g.Key.serialnbr,
                                   TrailerNumber = (g.Key.trailer ?? "N/A"),
                                   Shipped = g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp),
                                   ETA = null,
                                   ShipTo = g.Key.shipto == "1026" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) :
                                   g.Key.shipto == "2020" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(195) :
                                   g.Key.shipto == "2017" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) : 
                                   g.Key.shipto == "nor" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) : null
                         });
return View(TestingLinq);
```

And then in my view I have the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestingMainPage.Models.RecieveTruck>
@if (Model.Count() > 1 )
        {
            foreach (var tl in Model)
            {              
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="bodyTextTL"><img src="~/Content/images/view.gif" alt="View Load" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location.href = '/RecieveTruck/ViewLoad?LoadID=' + @tl.SerialNumber + ''" /></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="bodyTextTL">@tl.SerialNumber</td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="bodyTextTL">@tl.TrailerNumber</td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="bodyTextTL">@tl.Shipped</td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="bodyTextTL">@tl.ETA</td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" class="bodyTextTLR">
                    <input type="button" name="Receive Load" value="Receive Load" style="cursor: pointer;" class="bodyText6" onmouseover="this.style.color='orangered'; this.style.fontWeight='bold';" onmouseout="    this.style.color='black'; this.style.fontWeight='normal';" onclick="document.location.href = '/RecieveTruck/Execute'" />&nbsp
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
```

So my question is, how to I go about passing that through to my view so I can use it to populate the tables I am creating on my web-program.. 
I understand why it would not give me a error before running it, but how am I suppose to pass this to my view?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you understand what the error means and why you're getting it?

Comment: Try using the [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) methods. The `AddMinutes` cannot be translated to SQL by the provider.

Comment: And for those who use EF, there is also [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.addminutes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @deherch, should make a post instead of comment

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra, scartag already created answer below. I assume there is enough information here to solve Kyle Rickaby's problem :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to run that logic on the database itself - you can run it on the application server after you've selected the necessary data.

So change your query to just select the raw `shipTo` value. Then call `AsEnumerable()` which will pop you back into standard LINQ-to-objects, and calculate your `ShipTo` value there.

```
TestingLinq = (from 
...
select new {
                               SerialNumber = g.Key.serialnbr,
                               TrailerNumber = (g.Key.trailer ?? "N/A"),
                               Shipped = g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp),
                               ETA = null,
                               Timestamp = p.b.datetimestamp,
                               ShipTo = g.Key.shipto
})
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new ReceiveTruck { 
          SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber,
          ...
          ShipTo = CalculateShipTo(x.Timestamp, x.ShipTo)
  })
```

I've omitted the implementation of `CalculateShipTo` but you should get the idea.

Comment: Is my, running that logic on the database the reason for the error? Or would this just be an alternate route? Also, p is not in that context, and neither is b for your Timestamp, so even if I add that to the module (which I am assuming is just to use the calculateShipTo) will give me another error... This is like my second week with linq and this is a super complex (for me) query so I guess I dont get it...

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, ended up on another project in the middle of this one...

Answer (score 1):

You can use EntityFunctions instead. it's in `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`

```
EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime, num);
```

Comment: I am assuming you mean like this?

Comment: ShipTo = g.Key.shipto == "1026" ? EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime, 180) : because when I do that it tells me that... 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions' is obselete and has been replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions which I cannot add, also it tells me that DateTime is a 'type' but is used like a variable

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, ended up on another project in the middle of this one...

Comment: ShipTo = g.Key.shipto == "1026" ? System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes("DATETIMEHERE", 180) :